# To calculate wavelength, is a double-slit experiment or diffraction grating experiment better?

Tags: visible-light, waves, double-slit-experiment, diffraction, wavelength

Which one would give the most reliable results and why?

Even though in grating experiments you don't have to judge where the centre of a fringe is, wouldn't there be less fringes/principal maxima to measure across, thus making it more unreliable?

Answer (score 5):

Generally, the expectation is that diffraction-grating experiments will be superior. In essence, a double-slit experiment is just a diffraction grating with $N=2$ lines, and the difference between the two is that the diffraction grating adds many more sources that will coherently interfere. The core effect of doing this is that the diffracted lines become much sharper, which makes it much easier to measure their positions accurately, which generally beats any other factors at play.

Of course, the two are both very different and very wide classes of experiments, so comparing the two is a bit like [comparing the fighting abilities of sharks and gorillas](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/), and it's perfectly possible that there will be situations where a double-slit experiment will be superior. However, the advantage granted by the sharpness of the diffraction lines is so strong that those situations will be few and far between.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but wouldn't a diffraction grating experiment have less maxima to measure, so that any error in measurement instantly becomes significant, unlike the double slit?

Comment: (1) No, it doesn't have fewer maxima -- it has as many maxima as will fit in your geometry and as the coherence of your source will allow; you can in principle have arbitrarily many orders of diffraction (corresponding to as many multiples of $\lambda$ of path difference between adjacent slits) as you want.

Comment: and (2) even if it did have fewer maxima, combining multiple different measurements is an incoherent process (whose precision will scale with $\sqrt{N}$ for $N$ the number of measurements) as opposed to the coherent integration in a diffraction grating (which scales with $N$, with $N$ the number of lines in your grating. As a rule of thumb, coherent integration will tend to always beat incoherent methods.